Embedding diagram of flat spacetime
I am trying to understand how embedding diagrams are drawn and how they are interpreted, so I'd start with the flat spacetime.
In spherical coordinates, metric for the flat spacetime reads
$$ds^2=-dt^2+dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin\theta d\phi^2\tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$
At 2D equatorial surface, $dt=0$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. It simplifies to
$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\phi^2\tag{2}\label{eq:2}$$
This is the line element in polar coordinates in 2D plane. I am not sure what the embedding diagram looks like for this line element.
Following the method outlined in example 7.7 in Hartle's Gravity: An Introduction To Einstein's General Relativity, it seems like I should equate \eqref{eq:2} with the line element for cylindrical coordinates:
$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\phi^2=d\rho^2+\rho^2d\psi^2+dz^2\tag{3}\label{eq:3}$$
(It is not clear to me why we should do this in the first place. I thought that one needs 2 variables (namely $r$ and $\phi$) to draw 2D surface specified by $ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\phi^2$ but why we need to use three variables $(\rho,\psi,z)$ to draw this 2D surface.)
So we need to find $(\rho(r,\phi),\psi(r,\phi),z(r,\phi))$ but due to axisymmetry, $(\rho(r,\phi),\psi(r,\phi),z(r,\phi))=(\rho(r),\phi,z(r))$. Then we have
$$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\phi^2=\left[\left(\frac{dz}{dr}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d\rho}{dr}\right)^2\right]dr^2+\rho^2d\phi^2\tag{4}\label{eq:4}$$
which give us equations
$$\left(\frac{dz}{dr}\right)^2+\left(\frac{d\rho}{dr}\right)^2=1\tag{5}\label{eq:5}$$
$$\rho=r\tag{6}\label{eq:6}$$
Solving this will result in $z(\rho)=c$ where $c$ is some constant.
I think the resulting embedding diagram will look like a flat disk with infinite radius. How do I interpret this diagram? Can I picture a literal flat disk in 3D space?
Also, I wonder what the embedding diagram looks like when $\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi$. In this case, \eqref{eq:2} becomes $ds^2=dr^2$ and \eqref{eq:6} becomes $\rho=0$. The resulting equation is $z(r)=r+c$ where $c$ is some constant. The embedding diagram looks like a light cone? How it is interpreted?

In the context of the embedding of a 2D manifold (curved surface) $S$, we are talking about how to put it in a 3D or 4D space. That is, the embedding is a map from $S$ to $\mathbb R^3$ or $\mathbb R^4$.
For example if we have a 1D manifold (a curve), whose metric is specifid by $g = g(s) \mathrm d s^2$, and the process of embedding it in a 2D space (a piece of paper, say) would be like drawing a curve on the paper. We can also embed the curve in 3D space, just like a wire in our physical world.
In this example, the paper has two coordinates $x$ and $y$, and assume that it is flat: $g_\text{paper} = \mathrm d x^2 + \mathrm d y^2$. Then we'd like to know how to specify the corresponding coordinates on the paper when we have drawn to the “$s$” position of the curve, so we write $x(s)$ and $y(s)$. We can probably draw $y = f(x)$ in some cases.
For the “wire” case, we need $x, y, z$ all being function of $s$.
We can call $s$ as interior coordinates and $x, y$ or $x, y, z$ the exterior coordinates.
So, the number of exterior coordinates used here are decided by the targer space of the embedding.
In Example 7.7. The author takes a 2D slice (7.41) of the wormhole spacetime (7.39), and then, embeds it in a larger space, in this case, a 3D space. The Figure 7.5 shows how the embeded looks like. Notice that the author cannot print a 3D object on a paper, so Figure 7.5 is actually the result, a 2D curved surface in 3D world, being projected to the 2D paper (as if the shadow of a wire in physical world, the embeded 1D curve in the 3D space, on the floor, a 2D plane).
I wish these explain your confusions about all those dimensions i.e. numbers of coordinates.
OK let's go back to what you have asked -- to embed a slice of a flat spacetime.
The slice you take ($t = 0$, $\theta = \pi/2$) is 2D, and you can embed it in a larger space, e.g. a 3D flat space.
Then you need to decide how the exterior coordinates (we can write $X, Y, Z$ or $R, \varTheta$, $\varPhi$, or $R$, $\varTheta$, $Z$, it just depends on you) correspond to the interior coordinates $r, \phi$.
You have the freedom to choose different embeddings, just as you can bend a wire in the world or choose how to draw a line, as long as the mapping is smooth and injective.
One way to do is just let $R = r$, $\varTheta = \theta$, $Z = 0$ in cylindrical coordinates, and you have the image of the embeddings as a flat plane in the 3D world.
Another way is that you take $R = \arctan r$, $\varTheta = \theta$, $Z = 0$, and this time it looks like a disc with radius $\pi/2$.
You can even take $R = 1$, $\varTheta = \theta$, $\varPhi = 2\arctan \frac 1 r$ (take $\varPhi = \pi$ when $r = 0$) and then you get a sphere with one point removed.
All the three embeddings are equally valid. However, as you can see, only the first way fits our intuition of the flatness, because we identified all the symmetry of the flat plane (translation and rotation) with some symmetries of the 3D space (translation alone $X$-$Y$ plane, rotation around $Z$ axis).

Thank you very much! Your answer certainty cleared up my main doubts.
